# Two questions with similar stats - one can be deleted by the owner, another cannot

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Yesterday I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72956599/getting-text-from-a-custom-usercontrol-using-binding). Today OP commented - "you realy helpt me" - and then *deleted the post*. The question has zero score and 1 answer (mine) also with zero score and not accepted.

I didn't think it was possible *for OP* to delete a post with answers, but thought that policy was changed. So I tried to delete [my own post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715034/how-to-get-default-value-of-optional-parameter-of-table-function) with a -3 score with 3 answers (currently no accepted, 0, 0, -1 scores), but got a red message saying "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)."

I removed the acceptance checkmark some time ago when I first tried to delete the post because I believe the correct answer to my question "It cannot be done reliably with the current version of software"

So why there are different rules for deletion?

and bonus question - how can I delete my own post?

Comment: "*I didn't think it was possible for OP to delete a post with answers*" Only if: a) it has multiple answers b) it has one answer which is accepted c) it has one answer with positive score. So, OP can delete their question if it has one unaccepted answer with non-positive score.

Comment: The detail is explained in [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

Comment: @AndrewT. ah, I was mistaken. I thought the total score had to be positive. Turns out, it needs an upvote, therefore even an answer with +1 / -1 would make a question undeletable by OP.

Comment: @AndrewT., when I clicked delete, I got red message "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)." - the link was not helpful, but apparently another exists

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

> You can't delete your own question if it:
>
> - has an answer with upvotes (even if that answer has a net zero or negative score)
> - has an accepted answer
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)
> - has an answer with an awarded bounty
> - has at least one other question that is marked as a duplicate of your question

So in the first case a question with one answer that has no votes can be deleted but in the second case you have a question with multiple answers so it can't be deleted.

Only a group of 10K users or a moderator could delete that question. The question then is, why is it necessary to delete the question and its answers? If you wrote a post explaining why the question and its answers have no value to the community then maybe some 10K users would delete it, or maybe it would [just get more downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect).

Comment: I want it deleted because instead of solution it got me downvotes. also in more than 7 years it got only 300 view and 0 upvotes on any answer, so it not valuable, especially considering that the real answer is likely "it cannot be done"

Comment: I might just add that 10K users can only vote to delete the question after it gets closed (which can be done by the same users but they would have to come back to cast their delete votes afterward).